# Why does the form not set $_POST['submit'] or pass the filename?

Tags: post, get, submit

The following code displays

```
"Array ( [MAX_FILE_SIZE] => 1000000 [caption] => banner )"
```

when I do a print_r($_POST). I cannot see what I have done wrong.

```
  <?php
      $zfilename='File name';
      $zcaption='Caption';
  ?>

  <form action="test.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
     <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000"/>
     <p><label for="filename"><?php echo"$zfilename"; ?></label> 
        <input id="filename" 
               name="filename" 
               type="file" 
               placeholder="file name" 
               autofocus required/></p>
     <p><label for="caption"><?php echo"$zcaption"; ?>  </label> 
        <input id="caption"  
               name="caption"  
               type="text" 
               placeholder="caption"/></p>
     <br>     
     <center>
     <button type=submit >Submit</button>
     </center>  
  </form>
```

I tried "get" as well, same result.

Answer (score 0):

It's because you didn't use any posted data in your PHP.

Do a `print_r($_FILES['filename']);`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the two answers supplied (one has been removed from the list???) with no luck. Went back to the problem first thing this morning and after checking some more found it was a simple error on my part. I used "type = button" when I should have used "type = submit". I had checked and rechecked every parameter except "type" :(